# rospy rqt - fullscreen?

Tags: plugin, rospy, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi again,

I need to make an RQT plugin use the full display. I don't want to have a title bar, even task bars of the underlying linux shall be hidden. This is dueto the fact that the resolution of the physical display is pretty small and I don't want to lose too much space to unneeded elements.

Do you have an idea on how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163066/rospy-rqt---fullscreen?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2014-05-09

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are options that help maximize screen space:

```
-l, --lock-perspective
                    lock the GUI to the used perspective (hide menu bar
                    and close buttons of plugins)
-ht, --hide-title     hide the title label, the icon, and the help button
                    (combine with -l and -f to eliminate the entire title
                    bar and reclaim the space)
```

Used in combination they get rid of a lot of space used by the overall rqt title bar and per-plugin title bars.

Unfortunately there is currently a bug with loading a perspective file and using --lock-perspective:

```
rqt --perspective-file tmp.perspective -l
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/rqt", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main.main())
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 59, in main
    return super(Main, self).main(argv, standalone=standalone, plugin_argument_provider=plugin_argument_provider, plugin_manager_settings_prefix=str(hash(os.environ['ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'])))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/main.py", line 530, in main
    perspective_manager.import_perspective_from_file(self._options.perspective_file, perspective_manager.HIDDEN_PREFIX + os.path.basename(self._options.perspective_file))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/perspective_manager.py", line 330, in import_perspective_from_file
    self._remove_perspective(perspective_name)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/perspective_manager.py", line 305, in _remove_perspective
    self._menu_manager.remove_item(name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_item'
```

(I'll look into fixing this.  One note is that the default perspective gets loaded fine with lock-perspective however)

Combining `--clear-config` with the other options prevents this issue.

It would also be nice to have `--full-screen` option to launch straight to maximized mode regardless of how the perspective was saved, and so the user doesn't have to double click on the window manager title bar or click on the maximize button.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the slow response time and this probably not being the answer you want.
rqt doesn't support a Full Screen mode.
The closest you can probably come without a redesign of underlying rqt is something like the rqt_robot_dashboard system here: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_robot_plugins/tree/groovy-devel/rqt_robot_dashboard

---

Originally posted by [Aaron Blasdel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3372/aaron-blasdel/) with karma: 211 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1